# Hide edit/add/remove buttons in Django admin table when field in list_display

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to hide the edit, add, and remove icons from the Django admin tool for a foreign key field.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

This is my code so far:

```py
@admin.register(Request)
class RequestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "name",
        "contact_method",
        "neighborhood",
        "adults",
        "children",
        "prescriptions",
        "volunteer",
        "status",
        "due_date",
    )
    list_editable = ("status", "volunteer")

    def neighborhood(self, obj):
        if obj.address and obj.address.get("neighborhood", False):
            neighborhood = obj.address["neighborhood"]
            if obj.address.get("details", False):
                return f"{neighborhood} - {obj.address['details']}"
            return neighborhood
```

It seems the problem is that I have also registered another model `Volunteer`.

```py
@admin.register(Volunteer)
class VolunteerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "contact_method", "neighborhood", "valid_ID")

    def neighborhood(self, obj):
        if obj.address and obj.address.get("neighborhood", False):
            return obj.address["neighborhood"]
```

However, I need to keep this model too. So, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to hide this icons by using custom CSS for `RequestAdmin` by specifying the file in an internal [class Media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/):

```py
@admin.register(Request)
class RequestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "name",
        "contact_method",
        "neighborhood",
        "adults",
        "children",
        "prescriptions",
        "volunteer",
        "status",
        "due_date",
    )
    list_editable = ("status", "volunteer")

    def neighborhood(self, obj):
        if obj.address and obj.address.get("neighborhood", False):
            neighborhood = obj.address["neighborhood"]
            if obj.address.get("details", False):
                return f"{neighborhood} - {obj.address['details']}"
            return neighborhood

    # This is required to use custom extra CSS
    class Media:
        css = {"all": ("volunteering/css/style.css",)}
```

The content of `volunteering/static/volunteering/css/style.css` is the following:

```css
.related-widget-wrapper-link {
    display: none;
}
```

This is how the app is structured:

[image]

This is how the table is displayed now:

[image]